Modify Client-Server Packets Before Forwarding in Go Using Pcap
I need to create a proxy to intercept packets that my client sends to a server and that the server sends to the client. My client always initiates the connection on random ports, so I need to intercept all this traffic going to port 2106 on the server, modify it if necessary, and then send it. I tried using pcap, but I’m not having success – the packet is being sent even before I call forwardPacket. I need something that will only send the packet through my code, not automatically, because I need to modify the packet at some point:
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "sync"

    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
)

func main() {
    devices, err := pcap.FindAllDevs()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, device := range devices {
        wg.Add(1)
        go capturePackets(device.Name, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func capturePackets(device string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    handle, err := pcap.OpenLive(device, 65536, true, pcap.BlockForever)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error opening interface %s: %v", device, err)
        return
    }
    defer handle.Close()

    filter := "tcp and (dst port 2106 or src port 2106)"
    err = handle.SetBPFFilter(filter)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error setting filter for %s: %v", device, err)
        return
    }

    packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
    for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {
        // Extract packet data without forwarding immediately
        packetData := packet.Data()

        // Analyze the packet before forwarding
        shouldForward := analyzePacket(packetData)
        if shouldForward {
            forwardPacket(packetData)
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("Packet discarded after analysis.")
    }
}

// analyzePacket analyzes the packet data and decides whether it should be forwarded
func analyzePacket(packetData []byte) bool {
    fmt.Printf("Analyzing packet... %b", packetData)
    return true // Modify according to your analysis logic
}

// forwardPacket forwards the packet to the destination after analysis
func forwardPacket(packetData []byte) {
    // Forward the packet to the desired destination
    // Here we simulate forwarding with io.Discard or another sending logic
    forwardingWriter := io.Discard // Replace with a real connection if needed
    _, err := io.Copy(forwardingWriter, bytes.NewReader(packetData))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error forwarding packet: %v", err)
    }
}

Can anyone help me with this? Is it possible with pcap? Do I need to use something like iptables but on Windows 11?

You can’t modify a tcp stream just by listening to it, the network is delivering the packets to the correct recipient at the network layer outside of your control. If you’re not an active part of the connection, i.e. not an tcp endpoint for each side like a normal “proxy” then you need to work like a network device at that layer. This is not something the operating system is configured to do by default.

Since my client is always initiated with a random port, the only way I thought was to redirect all traffic destined for ports 7777 and 2106 to my proxy, but I don't know how to achieve this.

Is there any possibility for me to redirect this traffic before sending it to the server or client?

Can you control the IP/port that your client connects to? If so, why not just make a standard proxy (i.e. client connects to proxy, this triggers the proxy to open a connection with the server and copy, with modification, packets between the two systems).

@Brits no :/ client connect from random port.

I thought about redirecting the packets to my proxy, but I don’t know how to do this in Go.

You keep mentioning how the connections are from random ports, but that’s how normal TCP clients work. What problem are you trying to solve? You can’t redirect packets from Go your go code, because that would need to be at a different layer outside of your code. I think you may be missing some networking fundamentals here.

Yes, I understood that I can't do this with Go code. I thought about redirecting, but since I'm using Windows, I'm not sure how to do it. I considered using netsh:
bash
Copiar código
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=7777 listenaddress=192.99.44.99 connectport=9099 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
but without success.

Based on your comment it looks like you are now trying to write a standard proxy. That being the case this question/answer may help (there are links to code samples). The important thing is that you need to get your client to connect to the proxy instead of the server (the proxy then connects to the server). Currently I don't think your question is answerable (PCAP captures packets, it does not enable you to intercept/change them).

The biggest problem is that I can’t identify/listen to the client’s port; it connects on random ports within a range of 500 ports. That’s why I thought about doing this redirect as it's done with Proxifier.

Please clarify what you mean by "the client’s port". I suspect you mean the source port, it's normal that this changes and is largely irrelevant in terms of a proxy. Your proxy would listen on, for example, 0.0.0.0:6000 and you then configure your client to connect to that (e.g. 127.0.0.1:6000 assuming the proxy and client are running on the same machine). If you are talking about the destination port then your proxy could listen to 500 ports if needed (but we have no info about the client so are guessing).

@Brits That's the problem; I can't get my client to connect to my proxy, so I need to redirect the traffic.

OK - so your client is connecting to a fixed address that you cannot configure? That being the case, you need a way to intercept the packet. On windows I believe WFP is what you need (c++ example). There are Go packages that use WFP but I don't know if they support what you are trying to do. Alternatively your router/firewall may be able to rewrite the packets.
